# WPF ObjectCollection to a List

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wondering how Can I bind my data from my MongoDB database properly. I am using the MVVM pattern, but not sure what is wrong on my viewModel when I intent to combine the data from the database to a gridview.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Morza.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Morza.Helper;
using Morza.View;

namespace Morza.ModelView
{
    internal class BillMetaDataViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<BillMetaData> _MyDataList;

        public BillMetaDataViewModel()
        {
            Database dbobj = new Database();
            MongoDatabase dtbase = dbobj.getDatabase;
            var collection = dtbase.GetCollection<BillMetaData>("BillMetaData");

            bool isKey = true;
            string attName = "Name";
            int attType = 1;
            bool isRequired = true;
            int attLoc = 1;
            int attLength = 30;
            int isDecimal = 1;
            int attAlignment = 1;

            BillMetaData _obj = new BillMetaData(isKey, attName, attType, isRequired, attLoc, attLength, isDecimal, attAlignment);
            BillMetaData _obj1 = new BillMetaData(isKey, attName, attType, isRequired, attLoc, attLength, isDecimal, attAlignment);
            BillMetaData _obj2 = new BillMetaData(isKey, attName, attType, isRequired, attLoc, attLength, isDecimal, attAlignment);
            collection.Insert(_obj);
            collection.Insert(_obj1);
            collection.Insert(_obj2);
            var query = Query<BillMetaData>.EQ(e => e.attName, "Name");
            var entity = collection.FindAll();
            _MyDataList = entity.ToList<BillMetaData>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<BillMetaData> FileObjectCollection
        {
            get { return _MyDataList; }
        }
    }
}
```

The ToList state that it cannot convert a general list to a collection. What Should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
_MyDataList = new ObservableCollection<BillMetaData>(entity.ToList());
```